# unable to select all check on ngonit using angular

Tags: javascript, angular

here i am trying to select all check boxes by using ngOnit but it is calling that function and by clicking it is calling the function then it is selecting all

.html code

```
 <div>
      <h2>Hello Angular2</h2>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Diameter</th>
                <th class="text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="all" [checked]="isAllChecked()" (change)="checkAll($event)"/>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let size of sizes ; let i = index">
                <td class="text-right">{{i + 1}}</td>
                <td class="text-right">{{size.size}}</td>
                <td>{{size.diameter}}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="sizecb[]" value="{{size.id}}" [(ngModel)]="size.state"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

.ts code:

```
  sizes: any[] = [
    { 'size': '0', 'diameter': '16000 km' },
    { 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km' }
  ];

  checkAll(ev) {
    this.sizes.forEach(x => x.state = ev.target.checked)
  }

  isAllChecked() {
    debugger;
    return this.sizes.every(_ => _.state);
  }
  ngOnInit() {        
       this.isAllChecked();

    }
```

below is my stack blitz url

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pzvusr

Comment: ngOnInit runs before the HTML finish to load.
so you cant run it with ngOnInit try to use afterViewInit extends.

Comment: In `ngOnInit`, you should call `checkAll(true)`, not `isAllChecked()`. And change `checkAll`, so that it accepts a boolean parameter (e.g. `checkAll(check: boolean)`).

Comment: could u modify my stackblitz @ConnorsFan

Comment: See [this modified stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tz4by8).

Answer (score 1):

your code is working fine. missing thing is you don't have a key `state: true` in your defined array. that's why it is not selecting all checkbox.

try this array

```
sizes: any[] = [
    { 'size': '0', 'diameter': '16000 km', 'state': true },
    { 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km', 'state': true }
  ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello Angular2</h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Size</th>
            <th>Diameter</th>
            <th class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" name="all" [checked]="isAllChecked()" (change)="checkAll($event)"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let size of sizes ; let i = index">
            <td class="text-right">{{i + 1}}</td>
            <td class="text-right">{{size.size}}</td>
            <td>{{size.diameter}}</td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <input type="checkbox" name={{sizecb + i}} value="{{size.id}}" 
                    (change)="sizes[i].state = !sizes[i].state" [checked]="size.state" [(ngModel)]="size.state"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

  and in ts
  try this array

sizes: any[] = [
  { 'size': '0', 'diameter': '16000 km', 'state': true },
  { 'size': '1', 'diameter': '32000 km', 'state': true }
];
```